# Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem and diffusion

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

In [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039607000137), the author proved the existence of a global compact attractor of the following system
[image]

And then the author deduced the existence of a periodic solution:
[image]

I feel like he somehow used a variant of the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem for systems with diffusion despite the infinite dimensional aspect of such systems. I know that the the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem fails even for dimension 3 ODE systems. Maybe here the diffusion does not affect the behavior. Do such Poincaré-Bendixson type theorems exist?

Comment: Okay. At first reading of this article I got impression that they've absolutely proven one thing: if these conditions are met, the "trivial" stationary solution ($u = 0, v = 0$? I don't know really) is unstable, but there is a compact absorbing domain that guarantees existence of non-trivial (in the sense above) attractor here. I also still don't see why this can be only a stationary or periodic solution. Hope that someone else can come up with explanation and clarify this.

Comment: Indeed, there is a generalization of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem to PDEs with periodic boundary conditions, see [A Poincaré-Bendixson theorem for scalar reaction diffusion equations](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00251553), by B. Fiedler and J. Mallet-Paret.  But the paper you cite seems to have nothing in common with that.  I would just ask the author:  Professor Gianni Arioli, Department of Mathematics, Politecnico di Milano, gianni.arioli@polimi.it.